# no operation allowed after statement is closed. Java, Mysql

Tags: java, mysql

I have this code:

```
public void saveGPSReading(GPSReader gpsRd){

String sql="INSERT INTO EventData(" +
        "accountID," +
        "deviceID," +
        "timestamp,"+
        "statusCode," +
        "latitude," +
        "longitude, " +
        "gpsAge," +
        "speedKPH, " +
        "heading," +
        "altitude," +
        "address," +
        "creationTime)" +
        "values(" +
        "'demo','teltonika001',?,61714,?,?,0,?,?,?,'--not implemented--',?)";

    try{
        if(!con.isClosed()){

            stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);

            for(DeviceEvent de : gpsRd.getEvents()){
                GPSElement gps=de.getGpsElement();
                IOElementReader ioe= de.getIoElement();

                stmt.setLong(1, gps.getTimestamp().getTime());
                stmt.setDouble(2, gps.getLatitude());
                stmt.setDouble(3, gps.getLongitude());
                stmt.setLong(4, gps.getSpeed());
                stmt.setLong(5, gps.getAngle());
                stmt.setLong(6, gps.getAltitude());
                stmt.setLong(7, (new Date()).getTime());

                stmt.addBatch();
                //String s = stmt.toString();
            }
            stmt.executeBatch();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception err){
        err.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

which gets called here:

```
public void readPacketData(){
    if(info.isValid()==true){
        for( int i =0; i< info.getRecords(); i++){
            GPSElement gps= readGPSElement();

            IOElementReader io= readIOElement();
            DeviceEvent dEvt = new DeviceEvent(gps,io);
            gpsReader.addEvent(dEvt);
        }
    }
    dbMan.saveGPSReading(gpsReader);
```

thats the only place where i call it and am getting that exception at the line

```
stmt.executeBatch();
```

> java.sql.BatchUpdateException: No operations allowed after statement
>   closed.
>           at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(PreparedStatement.java:2024)
>           at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatch(PreparedStatement.java:1449)
>           at DBManager.saveGPSReading(DBManager.java:64)

any help here?

am not closing anything here. not even the connection, at any point in my code

::EDIT::

so i followed your tips, changed the code to this:

```
public void saveGPSReading(GPSReader gpsRd){

    String sql="INSERT INTO EventData(" +
        "accountID," +
        "deviceID," +
        "timestamp,"+
        "statusCode," +
        "latitude," +
        "longitude, " +
        "gpsAge," +
        "speedKPH, " +
        "heading," +
        "altitude," +
        "address," +
        "creationTime)" +
        "values(" +
        "'demo','teltonika001',?,61714,?,?,0,?,?,?,'--not implemented--',?)";       
    try{
        Connection con= createConnection();
        con.setAutoCommit(false);
        stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);                   
        for(DeviceEvent de : gpsRd.getEvents()){
            GPSElement gps=de.getGpsElement();
            IOElementReader ioe= de.getIoElement();

            stmt.setLong(1, gps.getTimestamp().getTime());
            stmt.setDouble(2, gps.getLatitude());
            stmt.setDouble(3, gps.getLongitude());
            stmt.setLong(4, gps.getSpeed());
            stmt.setLong(5, gps.getAngle());
            stmt.setLong(6, gps.getAltitude());
            stmt.setLong(7, (new Date()).getTime());

            stmt.addBatch();
        }
        int[] updateCounts = stmt.executeBatch();
        checkUpdateCounts(updateCounts);
        con.commit();
    }
    catch (BatchUpdateException e) {
        int[] updateCounts = e.getUpdateCounts();
        checkUpdateCounts(updateCounts);
        try {
            con.rollback();
        } 
        catch (Exception e2) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    finally {
        try {
            stmt.close();
            con.close();
        } 
        catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }         
    }
}
```

with a new method to create the connection :

```
public Connection createConnection(){
    Connection con= null;
    if(con ==null){
        try {
            DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver()); 
            String c=Constants.DB.DB_URL+"?user="+Constants.DB.DB_USER+"&"+"password="+Constants.DB.DB_PASSWORD;
            con=DriverManager.getConnection(c);
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return con;
}
```

the same issue still persists

Comment: isClosed() returnes true only when u called close(), sooo you may have isClosed() = true and the database connection is not still open. And how do u obtain the java.sql.Connection

Comment: so, how do i check for a valid and opened connection?

Comment: @anfy2002us: you should add this as an answer, i think it is one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

anfy2002us already posted in his comment that your DB-connection **may not yet be open** (because isClosed only is true if it was opened and then closed).

If that is not the problem here (e.g. if you are really checking that the connection is opened before you enter your `readPacketData()`, then do it like in this example:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Database-SQL-JDBC/DemoPreparedStatementAddBatchMySQL.htm

We should explicitly handle a batch-fail and rollback-retry on fail.